# Showing a dynamic table in GSP where column & data comes at run time

Tags: grails, groovy, gsp, nested-loops

getting two arrays from controller and code is --
    Sql db = new Sql(dataSource_wldb1) // Create a new instance of groovy.sql.Sql with the DB of the Grails app
                        def ivrColumns = []

```
                    db.eachRow(ivrColumnsQuery) {
                        rsRow ->
                            ivrColumns.add(rsRow.name)  }

                    def ivrResults = []
                    db.eachRow(mssqlQuery) {rows ->
                        //print rows
                        ivrResults.add(rows)
                    }
```

one has all column names & other has all row data.as below-
      return render(view:'xref',model:[ivrcolumns:ivrColumns,ivrresults:ivrResults] )

getting data in below format-
    Columns
    [ClientKey, Abbr, ConfigKey, Federal, State, DMA, Internal, Wireless, CRssing,     CurfewExemption, CampaignID]

Data
    [groovy.sql.GroovyResultSetExtension@12f8d75, groovy.sql.GroovyResultSetE
    oovy.sql.GroovyResultSetExtension@12f8d75, groovy.sql.GroovyResultSetExtension@1
    roovyResultSetExtension@12f8d75, groovy.sql.GroovyResultSetExtension@12f8d75, gr
    tSetExtension@12f8d75, groovy.sql.GroovyResultSetExtension@12f8d75, groovy.sql.G
    ion@12f8d75, groovy.sql.GroovyResultSetExtension@12f8d75]

view code is---

```
<g:if test="${ivrcolumns != null }">
<center>Database Location - WLDB1      <br>DB Name - IVR_GUARDIAN  </center><br><br>
<table class="table loadTable" >

    <thead>
            <tr bgcolor="#f0f0f0" >

    <g:each in="${ivrcolumns}" status="ii" var="columnivr">
    <td nowrap>${columnivr}</td>
    </g:each>       
            </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <g:each in="${ivrresults}" status="jj" var="hed">

                    <tr>               
                            <g:each in="${ivrcolumns}" status="kk" var="col">       
                                    <td nowrap>${hed.col}</td>  ///please suggest how    to do it.
                            </g:each>
                    </tr>
    </g:each>


    </tbody>
</table>
```

now want to show in GSP page .i am able to display the column but having hard time to display data.not getting how the dot will be used to get correct data to each column.

Will appreciate any help.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that's just a sql result, you can just call ${ hed[ col ] } or ${ hed."$col" }

Comment: thanks Tomas.update controller code in original post.I tried both way but it show -                           org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.pages.exceptions.GroovyPagesException: Error evaluating expression [hed."$col"] on line [119]: java.sql.SQLException: Invalid state, the ResultSet object is closed.

Comment: Try calling db.rows( 'myquery' )

Comment: @sana If tomas has solved your problem then please 'accept' his answer. Press the green check mark on the left hand side next to his answer.